# How to avoid repeating of code in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Here, I am designing a project with vuetify and currently I was working on vuetify theme colors where by I can change the background color of Navigation drawer, menu bar and page but doing so I have found that I am repeating code again and again which increase my code length.So, now I am trying to make my code short. You can see below that I am repeating the code:

> colors: [
>           { text: "blue", value: "#2196F3" },
>           { text: "purple", value: "#9C27B0" },
>           { text: "grey", value: "#9E9E9E" },
>           { text: "pink", value: "#E91E63" },
>           { text: "orange", value: "#FF9800" },
>           { text: "teal", value: "#009688" },
>           { text: "cyan", value: "#00BCD4" },
>           { text: "amber", value: "#FFC107" },
>           { text: "deep-purple", value: "#673AB7" },
>           { text: "deep-orange", value: "#FF5722" },
>           { text: "green", value: "#4CAF50" }
>         ]

My code is here:

```
<template>
    <v-menu offset-y>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn v-on="on" icon height="40" width="40" title="Personal preferences">
                <v-icon class="mt-1" size="28">mdi-account-cog</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list dense>
           <v-list-item  @click.stop="dialog = true">
                <v-list-item-icon class="mr-2">
                  <v-icon color="red">mdi-select-color</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        Themes/Colours
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>

                 <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="400">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>Theme</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-btn
              v-for="color in colors"
              :key="color.text"
              :color="color.text"
              @click="changeTheme(color.value)"
              class="ma-2"
              style="width:150px;"
            >{{color.text}}</v-btn>
          </v-card-text>




        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
            </v-list-item>



            <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-icon class="mr-2">
                  <v-icon>mdi-bell-off</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                        Notification Preferences
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
    </v-menu>
</template>

      <script>


    export default {
        data() {
            return {

                   dialog: false,

               theme: "",
      colors: [
        { text: "blue", value: "#2196F3" },
        { text: "purple", value: "#9C27B0" },
        { text: "grey", value: "#9E9E9E" },
        { text: "pink", value: "#E91E63" },
        { text: "orange", value: "#FF9800" },
        { text: "teal", value: "#009688" },
        { text: "cyan", value: "#00BCD4" },
        { text: "amber", value: "#FFC107" },
        { text: "deep-purple", value: "#673AB7" },
        { text: "deep-orange", value: "#FF5722" },
        { text: "green", value: "#4CAF50" }
      ]
            }
        },
   methods: {
    changeTheme(item) {
      this.theme = item;
      console.log(item);
      this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = item;
    }
  }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see repetitive code. Which lines are you referring to?

Comment: @tony19 I mean that color part... Can't it be made to into simple form something like:  colors: ["red","pink","purple","deep-purple","indigo","blue","light-blue","cyan","teal","green","light-green","lime","yellow","amber","orange","deep-orange","brown","blue-grey","grey"]

Comment: The main issue here is you are not able to explain in simple words what's your main question is. If you are not able to explain the issue to others, most probably you will also not get any useful response or solution back either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<template>
           <v-btn
              v-for="color in colorsList"
              :key="color.text"
              :color="color.text"
              @click="changeTheme(color.value)"
              class="ma-2"
              style="width:150px;"
            >{{color.text}}</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default 
{
  data() 
  {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      theme: "",
      colors: 
      {
        blue: "#2196F3",
        purple: "#9C27B0",
        grey: "#9E9E9E",
        pink: "#E91E63",
        orange: "#FF9800",
        teal: "#009688",
        cyan: "#00BCD4",
        amber: "#FFC107",
        "deep-purple": "#673AB7",
        "deep-orange": "#FF5722",
        green: "#4CAF50"
      }
    };
  },
  computed:
  {
    colorsList()
    {
      return Object.entities.map(entitiy => ({
        text: entity[0],
        value: entity[1]
      }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want only the color part to be in single line. Example: colors: ["red","pink","purple","deep-purple","indigo","blue","light-blue","cyan","teal","green","light-green","lime","yellow","amber","orange","deep-orange","brown","blue-grey","grey"]

Comment: Well, then use the suggestion from @Excalibaard - `Object.keys(this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify the theme? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/

Simply provide a configuration object when initializing vuetify in your app.

```
// main.js or a separate file where you init vuetify

import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

const opts = {
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: { /* your list of colors */},
      dark: { /* another list of colors maybe */},
    },
  },
};

export default new Vuetify(opts);
```

If you need a new array from all color names defined there, you can use `Object.keys(this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light).map()`. If you're also using dark theme, you'll have to modify the code slightly to call from `this.$vuetify.theme.themes.dark` when `this.$vuetify.theme.dark` is true.

```
computed: {
  themeColors() {
    const activeTheme = this.$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'dark' : 'light';
    return Object.keys(this.$vuetify.theme.themes[activeTheme]).map();
  }
}
```

If you need to set new colors for light/dark, you can simply override the current theme with a new colors object based on the clicked item. This also gives you more control over which colors you want to override, you could only override Primary, but also Secondary, Accent, or any other semantic color name that vuetify uses for the styling of its components.